# Is referring to third-world countries as "low-IQ and culturally inept groups" acceptable here or considered racist?

Tags: discussion, flagging, racism

I've encountered an answer in which this exact phrasing was used (among others).
It looks racist to me, but I don't want to raise a flag if I'm not sure about the community guidelines... should this be flagged?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're referring to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/56813/20220), it's already been flagged by another user, so there's nothing you need to do. [Update: the answer has indeed been deleted, and the user suspended.]

In future, my advice would be that if you think something is racist, just go ahead and flag it. Racism is indeed against the Stack Exchange Code of Conduct, and will be dealt with by the moderators once it has been brought to their attention. Of course, different people have different definitions of what is and isn't racist, so flagging something doesn't guarantee its removal, but in this case, I'd say it's fairly cut-and-dry.

Comment: I'd add to this that you're not going to get an answer deleted, or a user suspended all on your own. Any act of moderation is going to involve multiple people or an elected moderator, so don't feel like you need to be 100% sure before flagging. If you're mistaken, the flags will just be declined with no harm done

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113364/discussion-on-answer-by-f1krazy-is-referring-to-third-world-countries-as-low-iq).

Answer (score 13):

Although I don't know the full context of this statement, it appears to be a textbook example of bigotry and racism which goes contrary to the [Stack Exchange Code of Conduct](https://politics.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Politics Stack Exchange is a community for people from all nations and cultures. Therefore we do not tolerate it when nations or culture groups are described in such disparaging terms.

Please flag such statements.

Comment: Maybe increase the lasting value of this entire meta-thread by explaining why it is 'an example' of such? Eg: Is your verdict based solely on the five words quoted from the post in question? Then *why* are they an example (no misunderstandings: I agree that they are, but here you seem to present just your own opinion on 5 words without that explanation). Are the words indicative of the rest of that answer? (I'd say: pretty much so.) Those using 'the words'  IRL (guess OP is not a singularity) might have trouble following your reasoning here (nevermind the subgroup not wanting to understand).

Comment: @LangLangC Someone living in a third-world country does not mean they are unintelligent. Someone having a different culture than you does not mean they are culturally inept. Hopefully this explains it well.

Comment: The poster then went to on to repeat the same things right after he got off suspension, including the re-use of "IQ".  Which I flagged.  Those answers got deleted again.  But he did not get suspended.  Might I suggest a lot longer than 1 week next time around?  I've seen 1 year bans for people (whose views I do not align with, so this is not based on me defending them) that seem quite excessive considering what I had seen them post and the general quality of their contributions.  If anyone deserves removal/1 year ban, the person discussed here is.